# Appropriate goodness-of-fit test for the negative binomial regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, poisson-regression

I have used the following Pearson $χ2$ test and the deviance test to assess the negative binomial regression using R as

#########################################

```
# Pearson's χ2 residuals:  
dat.resid <- sum(resid(model, type = "pearson")^2)
dat.resid
model$df.resid
1 - pchisq(dat.resid, model$df.resid)

# Deviance (G2) residuals:
model$deviance
model$df.resid
1-pchisq(model$deviance, model$df.resid)
```

###########################################

Results:

Goodness-of-fit (GOF) results for the negative-binomial(NB) model

```
Test         Value           df             p-value 
Deviance     63.787          58              0.28
Pearson      50.795          58              0.74
```

However, my collaborator commented that the goodness-of-fit test based on deviance and Pearson residuals is not valid for the negative binomial regression. It made me confused. I appreciate your suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Your collaborator is correct. Goodness of fit tests are only appropriate for binomial or Poisson glms when the variance is determined as a function a the mean. The negative binomial distribution has two parameters, including a negative binomial dispersion parameter as well as the mean, so the goodness of fit test does not apply.

Comment: @GordonSmyth How can we assess that the negative binomial model fits our data well? Is there any model evaluation measure like R-squared available for the negative binomial?

Comment: @Gordon Smyth: Sounds strange. Do you mean some particular gof test or something else?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I never noticed such a test. Most literature just compared negative-binomial regression with Poisson based on AIC.  I am concerned here that how is it possible to know that our model fits the data well. For instance, if we have R-squared > .90, we feel confident that our model explained most of the variance!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I am refering to the same gof tests as used by OP. My comment is a standard well known glm result. If there is an unknown parameter in the variance function (as for the NB) then estimating that parameter forces the residual deviance to be roughly equal to the residual df so it becomes useless as a gof test.

Comment: @Simpson'sParadox Yes, you can compute an R-square equivalent and plot residuals for any glm fit including NB glms (just like you would do for normal linear regression) but neither of those are goodness of fit tests. There's no gof test for normal linear regression either.

Comment: @GordonSmyth I used pseudo-R squared like and McFaddens as well, but the reviewer did not accept my metrics which made me more confused with the NB evaluation criteria. I used this formula:                                                                      $sR = 1 - fit \$deviance /fit\$null.deviance  $ to compute pseudo-R squared.

Comment: @GordonSmyth What did you mean by OP?

Comment: @Simpson'sParadox Yes, that is the formula for R^2 = proportion of deviance explained, but it not a goodness of fit test and it does not test the validity of the NB distribution. I suspect you may be running into problems with the reviewer because you are confusing these different things. If you want help with the reviewer comments, you could post a new question quoting the reviewer and asking for more open-ended advice about how to validating or justify your model.

Comment: @Simpson'sParadox OP = original poster. That's you.

Comment: @GordonSmyth The reviewer commented that the high pseudo-R square value does not imply that the negative binomial model fits the data well.

Comment: @GordonSmyth Here is my detailed post with R codes: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504842/evaluate-the-quality-of-the-negative-binomial-regression-model-fit                                                                              I spent an enormous of time on this, but still couldn't find a reasonable solution. I really appreciate your time! Thank you so much for your kind suggestions!