# Evaluate the quality of the negative binomial regression model fit

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, poisson-regression

Our response variable is highly skewed and there is evidence of overdispersion as well. We tried with the Poisson, and Quasi-Poisson models. Both Poisson and Quasi-Poisson models failed to satisfy Pearson's $ \chi^2 $ goodness of fit test. Then we used the negative binomial regression model. We used $pseudo R-squared $ to assess the quality of the model fit. However, we don't know how can we validate the use of the negative binomial regression model like we did for Poisson, and Quasi-Poisson models using the goodness of fit test. Is there any way to check that the negative binomial regression model fits the data well?

Our fit results:

```
glm(formula = Infected ~ log(1 + PopDensity) + log(1 + GDPPPP) + 
    LifeExpectancy + log(1 + HealthExpend) + Humidity + AvgHigh + 
    AvgLow + AQI + PM1 + PM2 + log(1 + TotalTest), family = negative.binomial(1), 
    data = df, maxit = 10000)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.9231  -0.8082  -0.2303   0.3280   1.8219  

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value         Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            8.992467   6.879656   1.307          0.19633    
log(1 + PopDensity)    0.137216   0.057273   2.396          0.01983 *  
log(1 + GDPPPP)       -1.636393   0.683709  -2.393          0.01995 *  
LifeExpectancy         0.024059   0.056888   0.423          0.67392    
log(1 + HealthExpend)  0.614003   0.326203   1.882          0.06482 .  
Humidity               0.003370   0.010989   0.307          0.76021    
AvgHigh               -0.062498   0.046816  -1.335          0.18710    
AvgLow                 0.061456   0.040870   1.504          0.13809    
AQI                    0.002927   0.003672   0.797          0.42867    
PM1                    0.016954   0.006471   2.620          0.01120 *  
PM2                   -0.021772   0.006481  -3.359          0.00139 ** 
log(1 + TotalTest)     0.809103   0.091449   8.848 0.00000000000237 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(1) family taken to be 0.8757727)

    Null deviance: 200.335  on 69  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  63.787  on 58  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1373
```

```
# Pseudo R-squared

pR32 = 1 - p3$deviance /p3$null.deviance
pR32

[1] 0.6815972
```

Q-Q plot:

[image]

Distribution of the response variable, Y:

[image]

Simulation using the DHARMA package

[image]

Comment: The conditional distribution of Y is highly discrete, and therefore grossly non-normal. Further, this is the point of the NB model: to model a specific, discrete non-normal distribution. So other than for providing insights into the data (which are better accomplished using other graphs), there no use for the normal q-q plot here. A first thing I would like to see is a frequency distribution of Y.

Comment: @BigBendRegion I added the distribution of Y.  My concern here is: How can we say that our negative binomial regression model fits the data well?

Comment: "Fits well" is always relative, because all models are wrong. At least the frequency distribution provides no red flags. You can try alternative models for discrete Y including different discrete distributions, quadratic X terms and interactions, etc and compare likelihood based statistics (such as AIC) to see which models fit *better*.

Comment: @BigBendRegion Since Pseudo R-squared = 0.68, Can I say that my model was not bad? How can I favor my model? I am not sure why my reviewer commented that my model did not fit the data well! By the way, interactions did not workout well.

Comment: Why did the reviewer say it was bad?

Comment: @BigBendRegion They did not mention it which made me puzzled. I don't know how can I tell them my model is good. My only strength is Pseudo R-squared
. Is it enough?

Comment: Now that I look at your data plot closely, it is quite a red flag that your Y values are so high, and also approximately continuous. Those characteristics indeed do not fit NB or Poisson very well, so in that sense would agree with the reviewer.  I had originally thought that the numbers on the horizontal axis were 0,1,2,3, etc., with lots of zeros, as would be expected for NB and Poisson. So instead, maybe a log transform and ordinary regression would work.  In any event, it does not look like a good case for Poisson or NB to me.

Comment: @BigBendRegion Y is a case count in my model. I tried with log-transformed regression, but got adjusted R-squared = .13 !

Comment: @BigBendRegion OP's post arises from a previous post and discussion I had with them. I'm glad you are helping them as I don't have more time. But some things about the question concern me 1) An arbitrary value theta=1 has been input for the NB variance parameter instead of estimating it. That is not justified IMO. 2) OP claims to have done a gof test for a quasi-Poisson, but that is impossible. 3) It appears that a quasi-NB glm has been fitted instead of an ordinary NB glm (judging from R's message about a dispersion parameter).

Comment: Here is a validation exercise.  (1) Fit the NB model and estimate the parameters.  (2) Simulate data Y for a particular setting (like means or modes) of the X variables using the NB distribution. (3) Examine the simulated data.  Do they look like your actual data?  I am guessing no. That is why the NB model is bad.  1/2

Comment: Now, repeat using log transformed Y but use the normal distribution, and exponentiate the results of the simulation.  Which simulated data look more like your actual data? The model that produces data more similar to what you actually observed is the better model. The R-squared and pseudo R-squared are not useful for this comparison; this  exercise is.  2/2

Comment: @BigBendRegion I got the following error using glm.nb function as suggested by Professor Smyth : Error in glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, etastart = eta, offset = offset, : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x' I guess this because of too many variables! It works well for a few variables.

Comment: They used the glm function what I did. https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/STK3100/h14/lectures/lecture5.pdf I am struggling to find appropriate materials related to the negative binomial regression. Even no textbook uses the simulation technique that you have described. @BigBendRegion

Comment: The main point here is to understand statistical models as *producers of data*. As such, the validity of any model is determined by its ability to produce data that look like what you can actually observe. The ideas are in Understanding Regression Analysis: A Conditional Distribution Approach.  See Chapter 14 in particular.

Comment: Here is a something real simple to do:  Find the mean and variance of your Y variable, absent any X's. Use those as inputs into the R function in the MASS library "rnegbin": The second parameter tau is related to the variance by var(y) = mu + mu^2/tau, so you need a little algebra. Now simulate Y data according to that model. Compare those results with yours. In particular, see how many 0's there are in the simulated data - is that what you have?  Reasonable agreement between those two would be a good sign for the negative binomial model; gross differences mean that you need a different model.

Comment: @BigBendRegion I have added my simulated results in the OP. I have used DHARMA package to perform simulation according to this description. https://www.middleprofessor.com/files/applied-biostatistics_bookdown/_book/generalized-linear-models-i-count-data.html. Will it work for my case?